# Alguém poderia me ajudar a deixar um content responsive?

Tags: css

Bom eu estou criando um site vertical one page, e eu queria criar um content padrão para utilizar em todas sections da pagina ( para poder deixar centralizado )
Alguém poderia me ajudar? Estava tentando trabalhar com %, mas não deu mt certo..

A pagina é assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria criar uma div com nome de class content para deixar todo o conteudo do site dentro dessa div com um tamanho predefinido ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não precisa ser exatamente desse tamnho se alguém poder pelo menos me ajudar com um exemplo ..

codigo :

```css
html, body, .page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .6s ease-out;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

* {
  font-family: 'open sans', 'lato', 'helvetica', sans-serif;
}

.page {
  position: absolute;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

#p1 {
  left: 0;
}

#p2, #p3, #p4, #p5 {
  left: -200%;
}

#p1 { background: darkslateblue; }
#p2 { background: tomato; }
#p3 { background: gold; }
#p4 { background: deeppink; }
#p5 { background: rebeccapurple; }

#t2:target #p2,
#t3:target #p3,
#t4:target #p4,
#t5:target #p5 {
  transform: translateX(200%);
  transition-delay: .2s !important;
}

#t2:target #p1 .icon, 
#t3:target #p1 .icon,
#t4:target #p1 .icon,
#t5:target #p1 .icon {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
}

.icon {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
}

ul .icon:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.page .icon .title {
  line-height: 2;
}




ul {
  background-color: seagreen;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
 }



a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title, .hint {
  display: block;
}

.title {
  font-size: 38px;
}

.hint {
  font-size: 13px;
}

#p4 .hint {
  display: inherit !important;
}

.hint a {
  color: yellow;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}

.hint a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}

.line-trough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.page .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10%;
  left: 0;
  width: 270px;
  height: 170px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /*transform: translateX(360%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(360%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(360%);
  -o-transform: translateX(360%);
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.25, 1, .5, 1.25);
  -webkit-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.25, 1, .5, 1.25);
  -moz-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.25, 1, .5, 1.25);
  -o-transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.25, 1, .5, 1.25);*/
}

.page#p1 .icon {
  height: 220px;
}

.page#p1 .icon {
  transform: translateX(10%) !important;
}

#t2:target .page#p2 .icon,
#t3:target .page#p3 .icon,
#t4:target .page#p4 .icon,
#t5:target .page#p5 .icon {
  transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -moz-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  -o-transform: translateX(0) !important;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}



#_opcoes_main{
   font-size: 0;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   color: #444;
}

._opcoes_div{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px 0;
   vertical-align: top;
   font-size: 18px;
   width: calc(100% / 3.5);
   min-width: 300px;
}

._opcoes_div em{
   color: #2896c8;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;
}

._opcoes_div p{
   font-size: .8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 3px 0;
}

._opcoes_div select{
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   width: 200px;
   font-size: .8em;
}

._opcoes_div img{
   height: 120px;
   margin: 70px 0 35px;
}

#_botao_valor{
   font-size: 0;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 0;
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#_botao_valor:hover{
   filter: grayscale(0%);
}

#_botao_valor div{
   font-size: 18px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(1){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: #eff2f4;
   padding: 12px;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#_botao_valor div:nth-child(2){
   font-weight: bold;
   background: green;
   padding: 12px 20px;
   color: #fff;
}


#_errmsg{
   color: #f30;
   font-size: 18px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#_botao label{
   font-size: 16px;
}

#_botao label #_email{
   font-size: 18px;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 3px 0 20px;
   width: 270px;
}

#_modal{
   display: none;
   width: 276px;
   padding: 15px;
   background: #090;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 99999999999999;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 14px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 14px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   box-shadow: 0px 6px 14px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
   -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);-moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%);top:50%;left:50%;
   font-size: 20px;
}

#_modal_fecha{
   position: absolute;
   cursor: pointer;
   background: #000;
   border-radius: 100%;
   padding: 5px;
   top: -15px;
   right: -4px;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   line-height: 25px;
}

.contentpg{
 width: 1280px;
 top:50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/ct.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
 

 <div class="ct" id="t1">
  <div class="ct" id="t2">
    <div class="ct" id="t3">
      <div class="ct" id="t4">
         <div class="ct" id="t5">
          <ul id="menu">
            <a href="#t1">Vitorias/Wins</a>
            <a href="#t2">Elo Boost</a>
            <a href="#t3">Duo Boost</a>
            <a href="#t4">Melhor de 10</a>
  
          </ul>
          <div class="page" id="p1">
         <section ="EloJoob">
      <div class="contentpg">
     <div id="_opcoes_main">
   <form target="_blank" action="elos2.php" id="_form" onsubmit="return valEmail()" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" id="_valortt" name="_valortt" />
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>1.</em> <strong>Selecione a Liga e Divisão atual</strong>
         <br />
         <img id="img_ligatual" src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Liga</p>
         <select name="lig_atu" id="lig_atu">
            <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
            <option value="prata">Prata</option>
            <option value="ouro">Ouro</option>
            <option value="platina">Platina</option>
            <option value="diamante">Diamante</option>
         </select>
         <br />
         <p>Divisão</p>
         <select name="div_atu" id="div_atu">
            <option value="v">V</option>
            <option value="iv">IV</option>
            <option value="iii">III</option>
            <option value="ii">II</option>
            <option value="i">I</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>2.</em> <strong>Selecione a Liga e Divisão desejada</strong>
         <br />
         <img id="img_ligades" src="img_bronze.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Liga</p>

         <select name="lig_des" id="lig_des">
            <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
            <option value="prata">Prata</option>
            <option value="ouro">Ouro</option>
            <option value="platina">Platina</option>
            <option value="diamante">Diamante</option>
         </select>
         <br />
         <p>Divisão</p>
         <select name="div_des" id="div_des">
            <option value="v">V</option>
            <option value="iv">IV</option>
            <option value="iii">III</option>
            <option value="ii">II</option>
            <option value="i">I</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div class="_opcoes_div">
         <em>3.</em> <strong>Selecione a Fila desejada</strong>
         <br />
         <img id="img_flex" src="img_soloduo.jpeg" />
         <br />
         <p>Fila</p>
         <select name="_fila" id="_fila">
            <option value="solo/duo">Solo/Duo</option>
            <option value="flex">Flex</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <br clear="all" />
      <div id="_botao">
         <div id="_errmsg" style="display: none;">Erro</div>
         <div id="_botao_email" style="display: none;">
            <label>
               <strong>E-mail</strong>
               <br />
               <input onkeyup="$('#_botao #_botao_email label strong').html('E-mail').css('color','#444')" required="required" id="_email" name="_email" type="email" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail" />
            </label>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" id="_botao_valor">
               <div>
                  R$ 0,00
               </div>
               <div>
                  ADQUIRIR
               </div>
            </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
   <div id="_modal">
      Obrigado pela compra!
      <span id="_modal_fecha" onclick="$('#_modal').hide()">X</span>
   </div>
</div>
    </div>

     </section> 
          </div>
          <div class="page" id="p2">
            <section class="icon fa fa-keyboard-o"><span class="title">Type</span></section>
          </div>  
          <div class="page" id="p3">
            <section class="icon fa fa-rocket"><span class="title">Rocket</span></section>
          </div>
          <div class="page" id="p4">
            <section class="icon fa fa-dribbble">
              <span class="title">Dribbble</span>
              <p class="hint">
                <a href="https://dribbble.com/albertohartzet" target="_blank">Im ready to play, <span class="hint line-trough">invite me </span> find me</a>
              </p>
              <p class="hint">Already invited by <a href="http://www.dribbble.com/mrpeters" target="_blank">Stan Peters</a></p>
            </section>
          </div> 
          <div class="page" id="p5">
            <section class="icon fa fa-plus-circle">
              <span class="title">More</span>
              <p class="hint">
                <span>You love one page & CSS only stuff? </span><br/>
                <a href="https://codepen.io/hrtzt/details/pgXMYb/" target="_blank">check this pen "Pure CSS One page vertical navigation"</a>
              </p>
            </section>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

um exemplo : https://codepen.io/lucrovis97/pen/MvOrRJ?depth=everything&order=popularity&page=10&q=portifolio&show_forks=false

Answer (score 0):

João, quando se começa a desenvolver um layout responsivo, você precisa adicionar a tag responsável por dizer ao browser que aquele site é responsivo.

Vou deixar alguns links para você estudar e que irão te ajudar nessa questão de layout responsivo.

Primeiro leia este artigo,
[Design Responsivo na prática 2: do layout ao HTML](https://tableless.com.br/design-responsivo-na-pratica-2-layout-ao-html/), pois irá te dar uma base importante antes de ir ao próximo, [Desenvolvimento Responsivo e Viewport](http://blog.popupdesign.com.br/desenvolvimento-responsivo-e-viewport/).